# How to aceess child table fields using named queries in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two tables 
1) employee
2) Department
In this the department ID is foreign key for Employee table, and primary key for Department table .
Now I have write Named query in Employee persistence class. From this I am not able to access Department table fields.
But I am able to access By using HQl in Hibernate.

So Can any one please tell me How to access child table fields with Named Queries in hibernate.

Comment: Thanks to both                          Because both are given correct answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "I am not able to access Department table fields" you mean you can't use them in `where` clause:

```
select e from Employee e where e.department.id = :deptId
```

If you want to use them in `select` clause, to return them as query result

```
select d.name from Employee e inner join e.department d where e.id = :empId
```

If you show us what exactly works in HQL but doesn't work in named query, we'll help you further.

**UPDATE**

```
@NamedQuery(name="empdetails", query="select e from Empl e where e.department.did=:did") 

Query q = session.getNamedQuery("empdetails").setInteger("did", 1); 
List<Employee> li = (List<Employee>)q.list(); 
for (Employee emp : li) { 
    System.out.println("Employee Name is "+emp.getEname()); 
    System.out.println("Employee Sal is " + emp.getSalary()); 
    System.out.println("Dept id is " + emp.getDpt().getDid()); 
}
```

Comment: I have tried like that see below @NamedQuery(name="empdetails",query="select e from Empl e where department.did=:did")       This is in Persistance class and    In Main Java file   Query q = session.getNamedQuery("empdetails").setInteger("did", 1);
  List li = q.list();
  for (Object obj : li) {
   Object[] ao = (Object[]) obj;
   
   System.out.println("Employee Name is "+ao[0]);
   System.out.println("Employee Sal is " + ao[1]);
   System.out.println("Dept id is " + ao[3]);
      
  }

Comment: It is work with HQL              Query q= session.createQuery("from Empl");  
  List li=q.list();
  for(Object o:li)
  {
   Empl e=(Empl)o;
   System.out.println("Emp name is:"+e.getEname());
   System.out.println("Employer Depart Name"+e.getDpt().getDname());
  }

Comment: That is not anything like I suggested in my answer, but I corrected your code, check the update in my answer.

Comment: Thnks Finally I got it

Comment: I have used                                                         Query q = session.getNamedQuery("empdetails").setInteger("did", 1);
  List li = q.list();
  
  for (Object obj : li) {
   
   Empl e1=(Empl) obj;
   
   
   System.out.println("Employee Name is "+e1.getEname());
   System.out.println("Employee Sal is " +e1.getEsal());
   System.out.println("Dept id is " + e1.getDepartment().getDname());
      
  }

Comment: And Query is                   @NamedQuery(name="empdetails",query="select e from Empl e where department.did=:did")

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
@Query("select u from Employee u where department.departmentId=:departmentId ")
Employee Myfunction(@Param(value = "departmentId ") int departmentId );
```

Comment: I have tried like that see below @NamedQuery(name="empdetails",query="select e from Empl e where department.did=:did")       This is in Persistance class and    In Main Java file   Query q = session.getNamedQuery("empdetails").setInteger("did", 1);
  List li = q.list();
  for (Object obj : li) {
   Object[] ao = (Object[]) obj;
   
   System.out.println("Employee Name is "+ao[0]);
   System.out.println("Employee Sal is " + ao[1]);
   System.out.println("Dept id is " + ao[3]);
      
  }

Comment: Query q = session.getNamedQuery("empdetails").setInteger("did", 1);
  List li = q.list();
  
  for (Object obj : li) {
   Object[] ao = (Object[]) obj;
   
   System.out.println("Employee Name is "+ao[0]);
   System.out.println("Employee Sal is " + ao[1]);
   System.out.println("Dept id is " + ao[3]);
      
  }

Comment: In above I have stored all values in Object a0 and access them with Index values

Comment: Its not executing , It shows following error                                                                                             Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.unisoft.Empl cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
 at com.unisoft.Demo.main(Demo.java:29)

Comment: Here Demo class is my main Java class

Comment: May be That Query is correct but           I can't get idea to get that values with java code

Comment: With HQL is very easy                                                                                                           Empl e=(Empl)o;
   System.out.println("Emp name is:"+e.getEname());
   System.out.println("Employer Depart Name"+e.getDpt().getDname());

Comment: you have array of object so try this  List<Employee> employees= (List<Employee>)q.list();

Comment: Query q = session.getNamedQuery("empdetails").setInteger("did", 1);
  List li = q.list();
  
  for (Object obj : li) {
   
   Empl e1=(Empl) obj;
   
   
   System.out.println("Employee Name is "+e1.getEname());
   System.out.println("Employee Sal is " +e1.getEsal());
   System.out.println("Dept id is " + e1.getDepartment().getDname());
      
  }

Comment: And Query is                              @NamedQuery(name="empdetails",query="select e from Empl e where department.did=:did")

Comment: Means   I don't know that process